# Как работает ParticleSwarmOptimizer в PyBrain?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, pybrain

Всем привет, в общем есть у меня задача, надо оптимизировать структуру нейронной сети используя PSO (метод роя частиц). Я взял PyBrain и нафигачил функцию, которой подается 2 значения - количество нейронов на слоях в нейронной сети, а возвращает эта функция время затраченное на обучение.

Решил запихать её в PSO и результат - количество нейронов, при которой сеть обучается быстрее всего. PSO уже есть в PyBrain, вот только в доках про него 2,5 строчки и я вообще не понял как его использовать. Помогите, прошу, я уже половину инета обшарил.

Код прилагаю, но он кидает

> WARNING:root:Initial point provided was ignored.
>   WARNING:root:Something numerical went wrong. Stopped after 0 learning steps.

и выдает начальные данные, оно и понятно, ведь мне непонятно как это.

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.structure import TanhLayer
from pybrain.optimization import ParticleSwarmOptimizer
from pybrain.optimization import CMAES
import time
def nnAsFunc(sloi):
    start_time = time.time()
    net = buildNetwork(2, int(sloi[0]), int(sloi[1]), 1, bias=True, hiddenclass=TanhLayer)
    ds = SupervisedDataSet(2, 1)
    ds.addSample((0, 0), (0,))
    ds.addSample((0, 1), (0.33,))
    ds.addSample((1, 0), (0.66,))
    ds.addSample((1, 1), (1,))
    trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds, learningrate=0.1)
    k = trainer.trainUntilConvergence()
    net = 0
return time.time() - start_time


#Натренровали сетку на XOR
x0 = [10, 11]
l = ParticleSwarmOptimizer(nnAsFunc, x0)
l.size = 23
l.memory = 2
l.sociality = 2
print(l.learn())
```